# Is there a way to find out which files take a long time for Xcode to build?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

Is there a way to find out which files take how long to compile? Sometimes when refactoring I trip up Xcode's type inference mechanism and the project takes much longer to compile. If I made changes to a couple of files it can be difficult to find the culprit and manually reverting one file after another is annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add flag `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies` to your compiler.

This flag let the compiler to print out (inside report navigator) how long it takes to compile each function.

You can read more detailed instruction at,

http://irace.me/swift-profiling